# Selenium python - find element by data-value

Tags: python, selenium

this element is a multiple-choice region selector but I do not know how to interact with it.

HTML element

```
<div class="Input_select__uImQR Region_select__1h_yh"><span>NA</span><ul><li 
data-value="na">NA</li><li data-value="sa">SA</li><li data-value="eu">EU</li><li data- 
value="ap">AP</li><li data-value="kr">KR</li></ul></div>
```

When you manually click on the list the Class name changes to

```
<div class="Input_select__uImQR Region_select__1h_yh Input_open__3e__v">
```

code

```
driver.get("https://www.valorant.store/")
  time.sleep(1)
  clickshop = driver.find_element_by_class_name("SkinsBundle_loggedOut__3kG35").click()
  time.sleep(2)
  usernameshop = driver.find_element_by_name("username")
  usernameshop.send_keys(name)
  passwordshop = driver.find_element_by_name("password")
  passwordshop.send_keys("notmypassword")
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//option[@value='eu']").click()
  time.sleep(10)
  usernameshop.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Here is all the code(the account is for testing and you are free to use it)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import sys, os

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
skinfound  = bool(False)
while skinfound == False:

  driver.maximize_window()
  driver.get("https://www.valorant.store/")
  time.sleep(1)
  clickshop =driver.find_element_by_class_name("SkinsBundle_loggedOut__3kG35").click()
  time.sleep(2)
  usernameshop = driver.find_element_by_name("username")
  usernameshop.send_keys("sy9e0w6uimpc6fek")
  passwordshop = driver.find_element_by_name("password")
  passwordshop.send_keys("2ejly4ocpwifjbhj")
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@data-value='eu']").click()

  time.sleep(10)
  usernameshop.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
  time.sleep(10)
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//img[@src='/images/bonuscard.png' and @alt='Card Icon']"))).click()
  time.sleep(2)
  skins = driver.find_element_by_class_name("NightMarket_itemsGrid__9e2S-").text
  print(skins)
  if "Prime" in skins:
    print("A Prime skin was found")
    skinfound = True
  else:
    print("skinwasnotfound")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not see this xpath

```
//option[@value='eu']
```

in the shared **HTML**.

if this is the HTML

```
<li data-value="eu">EU</li>
```

you could write xpath as :

```
//li[@data-value='eu']
```

or

```
//li[text()='EU']
```

In code, you could use it like :

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@data-value='eu']").click()
```

or

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//li[text()='EU']"))).click()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

**Update 1:**

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get("https://www.valorant.store/")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='LOGIN']/.."))).click()
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, "username"))).send_keys('user name here')
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, "password"))).send_keys('password here')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class^='Input_select'] span"))).click()
time.sleep(2)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//li[@data-value='eu']"))).click()
```

**this should work for you.**

in case you need to handle pop up that appears sometime before login , you can use the **below code :**

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get("https://www.valorant.store/")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

try:
    if(len(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "(//i[@class='fas fa-times']/..)[2]"))) > 0:
      print("Alert is present")
      wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//i[@class='fas fa-times']/..)[2]"))).click()
    else:
        print("Alert is not present")
except:
    print("Something went wrong related to alert, may be it was not visible, but code will work")
    pass


wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='LOGIN']/.."))).click()
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, "username"))).send_keys('user name here')
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, "password"))).send_keys('password here')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class^='Input_select'] span"))).click()
time.sleep(2)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//li[@data-value='eu']"))).click()
```

Comment: I get a different error now  selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <li> could not be scrolled into view.

Comment: hmm...can you write this line `driver.maximize_window()` before`driver.get('')` and see if that helps

Comment: I still get the same error, Is there any more info I could send you that will make it easier to spot the problem?

Comment: yes you can send me page resource, in case you want to share it, You will need to save the source code into a text file, then upload that text file using file sharing website (free of course). they will give you a sharable link. That link you can give me.

Comment: @levlevon : I have updated the code above, the first one should work for you, and the second code will take care of the Alert that you see sometime (very rare but could be useful in future). additionally `time.sleep(2)` is just for visual purpose, you can remove that as well in case you don't prefer. I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

To select a region you first have to click on a drop-down menu.
Also it's recommended to use explicit waits instead of hardcoded sleeps.
With this two your code will be something like this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.valorant.store/")

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.SkinsBundle_loggedOut__3kG35"))).click()

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='username']"))).send_keys("username")

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='password']"))).send_keys("password")

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class,'Region_select')]"))).click()

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li[data-value='eu']"))).click()
```

Answer (score 1):

I can see the class name of the dropdown is changing when we are clicking on it, So by using `explicitWait` we clicked on dropdown, and further uses the static part of the class name which is not changing after clicking on the dropdown

```
driver.get("https://www.valorant.store/")
clickshop = driver.find_element_by_class_name("SkinsBundle_loggedOut__3kG35").click()
usernameshop = driver.find_element_by_name("username")
usernameshop.send_keys("Name")
passwordshop = driver.find_element_by_name("password")
passwordshop.send_keys("notmypassword")
```

Here we click on the `Region` dropdown

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[contains(@class,'Input_select__uImQR')]"))).click()
```

Action class is used to move to the element and click on the based on the XPath index, You can select any value just by changing the XPath index

```
action = ActionChains(driver)
action.move_to_element(driver.find_element_by_xpath("((//div[contains(@class,'Input_select__uImQR')]//li)[4])")).click().perform()
```